# Is it possible to have 2 django instances on same supervisord?

Tags: django, deployment, supervisord

I have a django application and two instances of it running on the same server: production and staging. I use virtualenv and each instance has its own env. They are configured as follows:

- **Production** (myapp.com): server runs on port 8001. Apache proxies 80 to 8001.
- **Staging** (myapp.com:5000): server runs on port 5001. Apache proxies 5000 to 5001.

Well, I put the server up manually and all **works perfectly**!

Now, I'm trying to use supervisor to manage and deploy them separately, for better organization and easier deploys. What I got is something really strange! The production server works fine, but the staging server responds as it was the production one!

If I do not use the supervisord, I acess myapp.com and myapp.com:5000 and see production and staging code running, respectively. However, when I do use the supervisord, I see the production code on both. It's strange, **it seems the supervisor sends the request to the wrong process**... :S

Is it possible to do what I'm trying? Is there known problems with having 2 webservers running on the same supervisor.conf? Someone has *any* clue, please? =/

---

### supervisor.conf (relevant parts)

```
;;;;;;;;;; supervisord configuration ;;;;;;;;;;
[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
;umask=022                   ; (process file creation umask;default 022)
;user=chrism                 ; (default is current user, required if root)
;identifier=supervisor       ; (supervisord identifier, default is 'supervisor')
;directory=/tmp              ; (default is not to cd during start)
;nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)
;childlogdir=/tmp            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
;environment=KEY=value       ; (key value pairs to add to environment)
;strip_ansi=false            ; (strip ansi escape codes in logs; def. false)

;;;;;;;;;; applications configuration ;;;;;;;;;;
[program:staging]
command=python manage.py celeryd -B --loglevel=info --settings=settings.staging
command=python manage.py run_gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=127.0.0.1:5001 --settings=settings.staging
autostart=false

[program:production]
command=python manage.py celeryd -B --loglevel=info --settings=settings.production
command=python manage.py run_gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --settings=settings.production
autostart=false
```

obs: the commands used for initialising the webservers are the ones on program sections above.

---

Many thanks!

Comment: Since `supervisord` does no such routing, that's not the problem. `supervisord` knows about sub-processes, and it does that fine in my production environments (managing 10s of processes per server). Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I will describe my setup using supervisor to attempt to shed some light. I have a single supervisor daemon managing 8 sites. In my case each *program* is a uWSGI process (as suppose to gunicorn). Each process communicates via a UNIX socket. I have separate nginx entries (as suppose to Apache) that bind to the respective socket (that the uWSGI process establishes). Likewise, each nginx entry is running on it's own port on the web server (optionally with a custom hostname).

The role of supervisor is to manage the lifecycle of processes, basically providing one point of control for each registered process by some name, e.g. `production`. I would not imagine the issue resides in supervisor *routing* to the wrong process since that is not what it does. Does that `run_gunicorn` command run the process in the background or the foreground? In order for supervisor to manage the process, it must not already be daemonized.

Comment: Thanks @byron. Right, nothing to do with the routing. Asking your question, when I run `python manage.py run_gunicorn --workers=2 ...` it stays in foreground. When I kill the foreground process one other worker keeps answering requests to the server. So, I guess the answer is it daemonizes itself, right?

Comment: Yes. I would assume the foreground process would be the _master_ process controlling two child processes (workers). If you are properly stopping the master, the child processes should shutdown as well. However, from supervisor's perspective, as long as that master process is running in the foreground, it should all just work.

Comment: I think you're right because I can do `supervisorctl stop production` and `supervisorctl start production` perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Supervisord [documentation about subprocesses](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment) says:

> Subprocesses will inherit the environment of the shell used to start the supervisord program.

My problem was I have separate virtualenvs for each instances but the supervisord process was first initialized using the production one. So yes, it's possible to have multiple django instances on the same supervisor, but not using different virtualenvs on each.